# JSON request sending empty data (swift)

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, xcode

My iOS app is sending empty data to the web service. I spent hours on finding the solution but nothing worked.
App is supposed to send a kontrah number to data base trough php script. Then data base has to recognize if the kontrah number can be found in data base. Then I'm getting a request from data base server if the number is correct. The problem is that the number I'm sending is correct for sure. I checked out what is being send to data base and it's all empty:

```
{"kontrah":null,"telefon":null,"opis":null,"afakt":null}
```

I've made the same app but on android in Android Studio using Java and everything works just fine.

My Code:

```
@IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let kontrah: String = fkontrah.text!
     let telefon: String = ftelefon.text!



    let json = [ "kontrah" : (kontrah), "telefon" : (telefon), "opis" : (selectedvalue), "afakt" : (selectedafakt)  ]

    print (json)

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(jsonData)
        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://hetman.pl/ios/post2.php")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData



        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                return
            }

            do {
                let t  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                print(t)

            } catch {
                print("Error  43-> \(error)")
            }
        }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wysłano poprawnie", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        task.resume()


    }

    catch {
        //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return(true)
}

}
```

Logs:

```
2017-12-29 15:59:43.867463+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] Failed to set (titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) user defined inspected property on (UITextView): [<UITextView 0x7fa1ad829e00> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key titleLabel.
2017-12-29 15:59:47.717492+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/bartoszlucinski/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3BE9103E-97CA-4E0B-AE53-6196EE08C49D/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-12-29 15:59:47.717874+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-12-29 15:59:52.225804+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 4072550144015629828_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
["telefon": "510356448", "kontrah": "1400-685", "opis": "Świnia", "afakt": "0"]
94 bytes
2017-12-29 15:59:57.074868+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] Failed to set (titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) user defined inspected property on (UITextView): [<UITextView 0x7fa1b0096400> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key titleLabel.
2017-12-29 15:59:57.628832+0100 Hetman4[10692:4029622] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <Hetman4.ViewController: 0x7fa1ac428ef0>.
Optional(["error": <null>, "result": kontrah  doesn't exist, "unAuthorizedRequest": 0, "success": 1])
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
$kontrah = urlencode($_POST['kontrah']);
$telefon = urlencode($_POST['telefon']);
$opis = urlencode($_POST['opis']);
$afakt = urlencode($_POST['afakt']);

$url = 'https://hetman.e4b.com.pl/api/services/app/zlecenie/FormAddZlecenie?kontrah='.$kontrah.'&telefon='.$telefon.'&opis='.$opis.'&afakt='.&afakt;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);


$results = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: did you try to use breakpoints and check if kontrah, telefon and other variables are null?

Comment: There are minor, unrelated issues in your Swift code (e.g. use `URL` and `URLRequest`, not `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest`), but it basically looks fine. The PHP looks suspect, though. (Why add `$kontrah`, etc. to the URL if you're building a `POST` request? Where is `$fields_string` set?) But you say that your Android app is calling the same PHP?

Comment: Android app is calling the same PHP (PHP file is not of my work but programmer from another company). One more thing. This code worked perfectly in September and I have no idea what happened.

Comment: @Rob Tried using direct URL but results where the same. Purpose of PHP is to pass only data that is recognizable by data base.

Comment: @Rob I couldn't copy and paste php code and had to write it manually and missed it here. my bad. They are in code tho

Comment: @Rob so what should I do? It doesn't work even when I'm sending request directly to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Your server is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, not JSON request. The response is JSON, but the request is not.
2. When I used `hetman.pl` URL, but it is redirecting to `www.hetman.pl`, but replacing `POST` with `GET`. When I sent request directly to `www.hetman.pl`, I got different messages. I can't read them, though, so I cannot comment whether this is better or worse.
3. Unrelated to the problem at hand, the Swift code can be tidied up a tad, replacing `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest` with `URL` and `URLRequest`, respectively.

Pulling that together, you get something like:

```
let parameters = ["kontrah" : kontrah, "telefon" : telefon, "opis" : selectedvalue, "afakt" : selectedafakt]

let url = URL(string: "http://www.hetman.pl/ios/post2.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setBodyContent(parameters)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    do {
        let t  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:AnyObject]
        print(t ?? "Invalid")
    } catch {
        print("Error  43-> \(error)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Where

```
extension URLRequest {

    /// Populate the HTTPBody of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request
    ///
    /// - parameter parameters:   A dictionary of keys and values to be added to the request

    mutating func setBodyContent(_ parameters: [String : String]) {
        let parameterArray = parameters.map { (key, value) -> String in
            let encodedKey   = key.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!
            let encodedValue = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!
            return "\(encodedKey)=\(encodedValue)"
        }
        httpBody = parameterArray
            .joined(separator: "&")
            .data(using: .utf8)
    }
}

extension CharacterSet {

    /// Character set containing characters allowed in query value as outlined in RFC 3986.
    ///
    /// RFC 3986 states that the following characters are "reserved" characters.
    ///
    /// - General Delimiters: ":", "#", "[", "]", "@", "?", "/"
    /// - Sub-Delimiters: "!", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", ";", "="
    ///
    /// In RFC 3986 - Section 3.4, it states that the "?" and "/" characters should not be escaped to allow
    /// query strings to include a URL. Therefore, all "reserved" characters with the exception of "?" and "/"
    /// should be percent-escaped in the query string.
    ///
    /// - parameter string: The string to be percent-escaped.
    ///
    /// - returns: The percent-escaped string.

    static var urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)

        return allowed
    }()

}
```

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot! I'm getting e-mail every time request is send and saw how much time you put into it. Again thanks a lot! You're awesome