# Swift Alamofire "+" sign removed from DB when request was sent

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

We're having this weird issue. The "+" is removed at the DB once we sent our request.
[image]

But if I print the `response.data`, I can see that the "+" is there (using Alamofire 4.9.1)
[image]

What could be the possible reason why the "+" is removed?

Here's how I set the request and the headers:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, @Rob. The string that I'm passing has the "+" sign, but for some reason, the "+" is replaced by " " at the server.

And this only happens when the request comes from the app. And it works via Postman.

I've updated my question above for the code, on how I set it.

Comment: Hi, @Rob. I've added above how I form the "requestString". Also, I tried setting the content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but still the same

Comment: Hi, @Rob. It's all okay now. I will post my answer below. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Completely unrelated (and I hope you forgive the observation), do I infer from the above screen snapshot that you are storing the password in your database? Seeing the same value repeatedly in your database makes me suspect that you aren't salting it and, encrypted or not, it isn’t very secure. Search for “best way to store passwords in database”, specifically using salted, one-way encryptions, e.g. https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/best-way-store-passwords-database.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future readers, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests must be “percent encoded”, replacing the `+` character with `%2B`. But there are actually lots of characters that might need encoding, so it is generally best to use the Alamofire `request` method with `Parameters`, which takes care of all of those details for you. E.g. in Alamofire 4.9.1:

```swift
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": authorization
]

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": username,
    "password": password
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    case .success(let value): print(value)
    }
}
```

Or in Alamofire 5 and later, one would use `AF` rather than `Alamofire`:

```swift
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    case .success(let value): print(value)
    }
}
```

See the Alamofire usage document: [POST Request With URL-Encoded Parameters](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters)

---

If you really want to build the `httpBody` of the `URLRequest` yourself, rather than just percent-encoding only the `+` character, you might consider a more generalized percent-coding routine, as shown in [JSON request sending empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026136/1271826). The idea is the same as what Alamofire’s `Parameters`, namely build the `httpBody` from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the "+" is not being escaped properly. So I had to replace "+" with "%2B"

```
let requestString = "grant_type=password&username=" + encryptedTokenUsernameBody + "&password=" + encryptedTokenPasswordBody
     
let encodedString = requestString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```